# Sort String Array by Date

Tags: swift

I have `var sortedSections = [String]()` that are date strings like:

`["Jul 18, 2017", "Jun 13, 2017", "Jun 15, 2017"]`

Is there a best (Swifty) way to sort this by date so the order is sorted (like this?)...

`["Jun 13, 2017", "Jun 15, 2017", "Jul 18, 2017"]`

Whatever I'm trying is too complicated:

```
var convertedArray: [Date] = []
for sorted in (self?.sortedSections)! {
    let date = String.dateFromString(dateString: sorted)
    convertedArray.append(date)
}
convertedArray.sort(by: {$0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending})
print(convertedArray)

for sorted in convertedArray {
    let date = Date.dateToString(date: sorted)
    sortedSections.append(date) // Except this is adding it to the array which is not right
}
```

Comment: To be able to sort the dates you have to convert them to `Date` objects.

Comment: @vadian thanks! yeah I was doing that, but then having to convert it back to a string again and so on, so I didn't think whatever I was doing was right

Comment: You can do `youArrayOfDatesString.sort(by:{String.dateFromString(dateString:$0).compare(String.dateFromString(dateString:$1)) == . orderedAscending}` (pseudo code not tested), but the logic of sorting, using a `DateFormatter` is the same.

Comment: Yes!  This was the missing piece, makes perfect sense.  Thanks @Larme